# Geometric interpretation of the complex identity $\left|1-e^{(2k-1)\pi/n}\right| = 2\left|\sin\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}\right|$ for $k, n \in \mathbb Z?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

For $k, n \in \mathbb Z$,
$$\left|1-e^{(2k-1)\pi/n}\right| = 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right|$$

I can prove this by expressing the LHS using cosines and sines, then simplifying the modulus.

However, is there an intuitive or geometric interpretation of this identity?

Comment: Do you need a factor $i$ in the exponent in the LHS? Also, why not generalize to $|1-e^{i\alpha}|=2|\sin(\alpha/2)|$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $0 < \alpha < \pi$  and draw a unit circle in the complex plane. The three Points $0$, $1$ and $P =e^{i\alpha}$ create a triangle, in which the angle at $0$ is $\alpha$ and the length of the Line $L$ from $1$ to $P$ is $|L| = |1-e^{i\alpha}|$.

Now denote the center of $L$ as $C$ and draw another line from $0$ to $C$. Because the lines from $0$ to $1$ as well as from $0$ to $P$ both have length $1$, the line from $0$ to $C$ halves the angle $\alpha$ and hits $L$ at a right angle. This means we can apply the geometric definition of the sine in either of the two subtriangles, i.e. $\sin  (\alpha/2) = \frac{|L|/2}{1}$. This can be rearranged to $|1 - e^{i\alpha}| = |L| = 2 \sin(\alpha/2) = 2|\sin(\alpha/2)|$.

The remaining cases for $\alpha$ can be verified by considering the symmetry and periodicity of the sine function.